# How to remove a div's content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How would I go about removing the content inside a div tag with the class `content`.

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

I would imagine it would be something like:

```
$(.content).remove
```

Separately, how would I go about adding a string of text inside that same `div`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.empty()` to remove the contents in the Div tag.

```
$('.content').empty();
```

For your second question; you can add the any text or content using `$('.content').html(newcontent)` or

```
$('.content').text(newcontentText); //specifically for text content.
```

Comment: You should note that if you are using `.html(newContent)` or `.text(newContent)`, then it is unnecessary to use `.empty()`.

Comment: As @Wolfram states, `.html(newContent)` and `.text(newContent)` will replace existing content.

Comment: @Wolfram and @@Lavabeams yes of course, probably i should have mentioned that. anyways the other answer has it...

Answer (score 6):

`remove()` removes the element, I think you're looking for `empty()` to keep the element, but remove everything inside it.

```
$('.content').empty();
```

to add a string of text, you would'nt need empty(), you could just do:

```
$('.content').text('My new string here');
```